# Is there a solution to combining bevel with subdiv?

Tags: subdivision-surface, displacement, bevel

The scenario is I have an object that needs beveled edges, but simultaneously I want to use micropolygon displacement, which requires adaptive subdiv. The problem is that bevels and subdiv surfaces do not get along well, because subdiv likes neat quad geometry, but beveling tends to create a mess. This leads to frequent artifacts.

It seems to me like Blender should have a bevel node that works with displacement (no, not talking about the one that bends normal). Since the mesh is already being subdivided to pixel sized polygons, it would be ideal to just calculate the bevel as a vector displacement, rather than through a mesh modifier. It doesn't seem like this functionality exists in Blender and I can find no discussion of such a method.

Comment: can you post a pic of the issue? and have you tried the harden normals option?

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz This isn't a problem with a specific model. This is a fundamental problem that I believe exists, and a tool that is missing.

Comment: It might not be a specific model, but when I tell you about artefacts, it can mean a number of things, a screenshot  would help. Also you can bake the bevel map and maybe overlay it with your bump / displacement map